# How do you configure microbundle-crl to not bundle files that are tests?

Tags: javascript, microbundle

I have my tests in the same folder as my module to avoid having to jump around the tree.  Is it possible to make microbundle-crl skip the test files when bundling?

I am trying to do it on my repo https://github.com/trajano/react-hooks-tests

Answer (score 1):

Its actually due to `tsc` rather than microbundle.

Just add in `tsconfig.json`

```
"exclude": ["**/*.test.ts", "**/*.test.tsx", "src/test-support/*"]
```